# Upper bound on expectation given probability

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X$ be a positive random variable. I know that $\mathbb{P}[X \leq a] \geq q$. Any hints about how to find an upper bound on $E[X]$ in terms of $q$ and $a$?
Using Markov inequality, I can obtain $E[X] \geq a(1-q)$. But I need an upper bound, not a lower one. Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: What exactely do you need?

Answer (score 1):

If $X=a$ with probability $q$ and $N$ with probability $1-q$ (where $N>a$) then $EX=aq+N(1-q)$. So there are examples with $EX$ as large as you want for a given $a$ and $q$.

Answer (score 1):

There does not exist any such upper bound. Take $\mathbf{P}(X=0)=\frac{1}{2}$  (here $a=0$ and $q=\frac{1}{2}$) and $\mathbf{P}(X=n)=\frac{1}{2}$, for $n$ integer. Then
$$
\mathbf{E}(X)=\frac{n}{2}.
$$
So we can make $\mathbf{E}(X)$ as large as we want. However, if we have
$$
\forall a\geq 0: \quad \mathbf{P}(X\geq a) \leq Q(a),
$$
then you may use the integral identity
$$
\mathbf{E}(X)=\int_{0}^\infty \mathbf{P}(X\geq a) \mathrm{d}a
$$
to get an upper bound.